# Несколько вопросов по PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Ребята, вот имею такую задачу - необходимо скопировать данные из одной схемы БД в другую в этой же БД (БД - PostgreSQL). При этом необходимо соблюдать некоторые условия. А именно:

> Insert :
>
> Load table incrementally using project_id as a lookup. Insert project
> record into this table when project_id does not exist.
>
> Update :
>
> If project_id already exists and the value of other attributes is
> changed, then update only the changed values for the collect project
> (project_id).

Пока не до конца понял сами условия, если честно. В связи с чем не могу правильно сформировать запрос. Сейчас запрос как базовый выглядит так:

```
INSERT INTO target_schema.supplies select * from source_schema.supplies
```

но уже есть ошибка:

```
2021-08-10 13:05:23,482] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - duplicate key value violates unique constraint "supplies_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/local_copy_source_schema_to_target_schema.py", line 31, in copy_data_from_source_schema_to_target_schema
    redshift_hook.run(sql_queries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 175, in run
    cur.execute(s)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "supplies_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

Другие условия даже не включил так как не понял.

Можете подсказать где ошибка в запросе исходя из условий и как доделать запрос чтобы все условия удовлетворялись?

Спасибо.

Пока только начинаю погружаться в SQL и еще есть проблемы.

P.S. Был вопрос - использовать ли ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE или же смотреть только те строки, где были изменения и обновлять, а остальное просто добавлять.

Пока остановился на такой конструкции:

```
INSERT INTO target_redshift.supplies
        SELECT s.*
        FROM source_redshift.supplies AS s
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM target_redshift.supplies AS t WHERE s.project_id = t.project_id)
        ON conflict
        DO nothing;
```

Вроде так должно быть чуть быстрее, чем делать ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE. Что скажете?

Comment: Ну так используйте `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` же... *Пока не до конца понял сами условия, если честно.* А что тут понимать? если нет записи с таким проектом - вставить, если есть - обновить данные в существующей записи. Всё.

Comment: А правильно будет добавить ON CONFLICT (project_id) DO UPDATE SET * = EXCLUDED.*;? Если мне нужно обновить все значения кроме project_id?

Comment: Звезды - забудь про них навсегда, кроме как в COUNT(*). Везде - только список полей, поштучно. *Если мне нужно обновить все значения кроме project_id* то для каждого значения, кроме project_id, пиши выражение присвоения.

Comment: Я понимаю, что звезды - это плохо. Но что, если я укажу список, а потом через какое-то время в таблице добавятся новые колонки?

Comment: Если изменилась структура и добавились новые колонки, то и код, обрабатывающий новые данные, тоже должен измениться. Вот заодно и текст запроса подкорректируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модифицированный запрос выглядит сейчас у меня так:

```
INSERT INTO target_redshift.supplies
        SELECT s.id, s.name, s.description, s.manufacturer
        FROM source_redshift.supplies AS s
        ON CONFLICT (project_id)
        DO UPDATE SET
        (name, description, manufacturer) = (EXCLUDED.name, EXCLUDED.description, EXCLUDED.manufacturer)
```

Благодарность @Akina!